# why is a page_load significant in aspx.cs?

Tags: asp.net

Can someone explain to me the sheer purpose of a page load? My code runs just fine without it right now in my aspx.cs (codebehind) file. I am doing very basic stuff here, so im guessing it has a lot of importance somewhere so i am just wondering what that would be. thanks for any help!

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: speaking in simple words, Page_load is a method that asp.net is providing for us developers to work on. Asp.Net does not need a Page_Load event to work. Events are just methods that are fired at some point of time during a page is preocessed.

Answer (score 2):

You should check about the Page Life Cycle.
The load is an event in this Cycle.

About the method, `Page_load()` is the method on the server side application, for an `.aspx` file. All code inside of this method is executed once at the beginning of the page.
Also, in the load, if the current request is a postback, control properties are loaded with information recovered from view state and control state. (Different from initialize, when you set the default values)
So, in the `Load Event`, the Page object calls the `OnLoad` method on the `Page object`, and then recursively does the same for each child control until the page and all controls are loaded. The Load event of individual controls occurs after the Load event of the page.

Some links for you:

[ASP .NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

[Page_Load and Postback](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_events.asp)

and there are a few more in Google